# Update records from associated model before deleting a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I'm having the following models

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  before_destroy :reset_posts_category

  def reset_posts_category
    ???
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

What I'd like to do is to create a callback, so right before deleting a category to update all posts **that belong to this category** to set the default value (`post.category_id = 0`). How can I do this?

Comment: Does `has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify` work for you too? Or do you realy need to set `category_id`  to 0 instead of  `null`?

Comment: @slowjack2k is it going to update the records in the database or is it just setting the posts object to nil? the logic is, when you delete a category, any post that belongs to this category should set back to the default, so there would be no orphan posts, or posts that have a `category_id` that doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at option `:dependent` of `has_many`

When you change your code to 
`has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify` Rails automaticaly sets all `posts` within your database to `null`.

Other `dependent` options are:

- `:destroy`  calls destroy on all objects with callbacks
- `:delete_all`  delete all records directly from db without callbacks
- `:restrict_with_exception`  raise an exeption if a record exists
- `:restrict_with_error`  add an error to `errors

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :nullify
end
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts

  before_destroy :reset_posts_category

  def reset_posts_category
    self.posts.update_all(category_id: 0)
  end
end
```

You can also go with `dependent :nullify` as said by @Hardik Upadhyay and  @slowjack2k which will be better than updating the `category_id: 0`.